# getting rxjs value in sync, is this an anti pattern?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I often find myself having to just get a value from the store and do something like this which seems like an anti pattern (side effect of remembering r) and wonder if there is a better way.

```
    getAssetName(i_page: IPager): string {
        let r = '';
        if (i_page.Player[0].$.src) {
            this.storeSelector.getScene(i_page.Player[0].$.src)
                .take(1)
                .subscribe((v) => {
                    r = v.Player.$.label;
                });
        } else {
            this.storeSelector.getResource(i_page.Player[0].Data[0].Resource[0].$.resource)
                .take(1)
                .subscribe((v) => {
                    r = v.resource_name;
                });
        }
        return r;
    }
```

in other words, a better way of getting value 'r' without having to closure it?

now, I am using Angular and am aware I can use 'async' as in

```
{{ getAssetName$(element.pager) | async | truncate:[maxStringSize]}}

this.getAssetName$ = this.getAssetName;


 getAssetName(i_page: IPager): Observable<string> {
        if (i_page.Player[0].$.src) {
            return this.storeSelector.getScene(i_page.Player[0].$.src)
                .map((v) => {
                    return v.Player.$.label;
                });
        } else {
            return this.storeSelector.getResource(i_page.Player[0].Data[0].Resource[0].$.resource)
                .map((v) => {
                    return v.resource_name;
                });
        }
    }
```

but trying to see if there is a way to do without `async` template method.
If I use the async without onPush template performance degradation is visible

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the value at this level? Can't you just delay this until you need to show the value?

Comment: because I have to modify the data before I create the custom data structure which I am passing into the template. I did mofify my question a bit so please re-read. TX!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [BehaviourSubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject), it is a variant of `Subject`, so you can use it as observable using the method `asObservable` and get the value in sync with the method `getValue`.

Example:

```js
public scene$: BehaviourSubject<any> = new BehaviourSubject(null); // needs a first value
public resource$: BehaviourSubject<any> = new BehaviourSubject(null);;

...
scene$.next(newValue); // update current value of scene

...
scene$.asObservable().subscribe(console.log) // async
scene$.getValue() // sync
```

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to go about this - below are three possible solutions.

Since you're only getting one result you can use `.toPromise()` as a cleaner way to convert the stream to return an async result.

```
async getAssetName(i_page: IPager): string {
  const assetSrc = (i_page.Player[0].$.src)
    ? this.storeSelector.getScene(i_page.Player[0].$.src).pipe(map(x => x.Player.$.label))
    : this.storeSelector.getResource(i_page.Player[0].Data[0].Resource[0].$.resource)
      .pipe(map(x => x.resource_name));
  return await assetSrc.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
}
```

If you want to avoid the async entirely, and you want to get the name as part of constructing a bigger object, then that construction can cleanly be done within the stream itself.

```
template: MyTemplate;

private getAssetName$(i_page: IPager): Observable<string> {
  const assetSrc = (i_page.Player[0].$.src)
    ? this.storeSelector.getScene(i_page.Player[0].$.src).pipe(map(x => x.Player.$.label))
    : this.storeSelector.getResource(i_page.Player[0].Data[0].Resource[0].$.resource)
       .pipe(map(x => x.resource_name));
  return assetSrc.pipe(take(1));
}

createTemplate(i_page: IPager, /* other stuff */) {
  // you can skip the fork join if you're just using one observable.
  forkJoin(this.getAssetName(i_page), /* other observables if necessary*/).pipe(
    subscribe(([assetName, /* other results */]) => {
      this.template = { assetName, /* other stuff */ };
    })
  );
}
```

I am not a huge fan of doing this this way.  If possible, I'd make the template itself an observable.

To build the template I combine all the latest changes from all Observables that are needed for construction.  When the pager is changed, a subject is fired.  That subject is linked to the retrieval of the assetName in the combineLatest using switchMap.  When the result is retrieved the template$ Observable is updated with the latest result.

```
private pageChangeSubject = new Subject<IPager>();
// like forkJoin the combineLatest is only needed if multiple observables.
// getAssetName is the same method from the previous example.
template$: Observable<MyTemplate> = this.combineLatest(
    this.pageChangeSubject.pipe(switchMap(x => this.getAssetName(x)))
  ).pipe(map(([assetName, /* ... */]) => ({ assetName, /* ... */ })));

pageChanged(page: IPager) { this.pageChangeSubject.next(page); }
```

Comment: first thank you for taking the time to reply with all this. I evaluated all options but honestly they all do seem a bit too complex .. from the current examples I would prob pick the | async in template but I would have to make sure the template is onPush to prevent the re-calls of subscribtion, or... use the "anti" pattern of const r... mmmmm

Comment: The great thing about the third solution is the use of `switchMap`.  If you get a bunch of calls the switchMap will cancel the previous ones so you won't get a bunch of refreshes.  You can also throw in a `throttleTime` operator before the `map` and a `shareReplay(1)` after the map.  That will limit a lot of repetitious behavior.

Comment: yes I understand, but in this case the calls are all sync, just getting data from the local store, not async to a server or db.

Answer (score 0):

after evaluating all I believe this is the best solution which is to use:

1. Angular async pipe
2. onPush to reduce multiple calls from template to method (important)
3. changeDetection mark for check when needed
4. cleaner if statement

Solution:

```
<template>:
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{getAssetNameAsync$(element) | async}}
</td>


<component>:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-scene-block-location',
    templateUrl: './block-location.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./block-location.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

...

constructor(priate cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

someUpdateHappeningAtStore() {
    this.cd.markForCheck();
}


getAssetNameAsync$(i_page: IPager): Observable<string> {
     return (i_page.Player[0].$.src)
         ? 
         this.storeSelector.getScene(i_page.Player[0].$.src)
         .map(x => x.Player.$.label)
         :    
  this.storeSelector.getResource(i_page.Player[0].Data[0].Resource[0].$.resource)
      .map(x => x.resource_name)
      .take(1);
}
```